# Is state checking always an efficient thing to do?

Tags: c++, performance

- Suppose that it is only necessary to bind a value to a certain
  datamember of a certain object when bState is true. When bState
  is false, it is not necessary, but it does not hinder either.

Which of the following pieces of code would be more efficient, and why?

(EDIT: updated, state is now a member of the object)

```
const int x;     
int i;
int iToBind;
Classname pObject[x];

for (; i < x; ++i) {
 if (pObject[i].bState) {
        pObject[i].somedatamember = iToBind;
    }
}
```

Versus:

```
for (; i < x; ++i) {
   pObject[i].somedatamember = iToBind;
}
```

Comment: I'd go with the latter, but why not just run both version and see which one is faster?

Comment: I'm guessing you've simplified your code, but as written you could move the `if (bState)` test outside the loop.

Comment: As always, the answer is: If you actually care, *profile it*. Likely there will be no noticeable difference - but that's just my personal prediction. Again, only profiling will tell.

Comment: does bState depend on pObject[x]?

Comment: yes, it does, I should have written the code more carefully. The edit should be correct now.

Comment: I assume that you would be indexing element `i-th` rather than always *one beyond the end* (`x-th`) of the array...(Undefined Behavior) Try to be careful when asking questions with code.

Comment: @delnan My question actually consists of two parts: 1) which one is more efficient and 2) why?

I'm 'fairly' new to C++ and only recently started wondering about efficiency, so I'm not sure how to profile stuff. But even if I would, that still wouldn't solve the "Why?" part

Comment: @David My apologies. I'm having a bad day :) Since corrected

Comment: The short story is that you shouldn't wonder about efficency, but default to assuming it's fast enough ;) Nobody can answer (1) without trying and the only way to be sure about (2) is to look at the generates machine code. Someone familiar with compiler optimizations (it's astounding how many people underestimate those or outright forget about them), the target architecture, the details of the language semantics, etc. may be able to make an educated guess. But again, that requires some in-depth knowledge of low-level details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say the latter is definitely quicker. The first version has bidirectional memory access, the latter has unidirectional memory access.

In this version:

```
for (; i < x; ++i) {
  if (pObject[x].bState) {
    pObject[x].somedatamember = iToBind;
  }
}
```

there is a stall during the `if` statement as the CPU must wait for the data to be read from memory. The speed the memory is read is dependent on where the data is residing. The further from the CPU the longer it takes: L1 (fastest), L2, L3, Ram, Disk (slowest).

In this version:

```
for (; i < x; ++i) {
  pObject[x].somedatamember = iToBind;
}
```

there are only writes to memory. Writes to memory do not stall the CPU.

As well as the memory access times, the latter loop has no conditional jump inside the loop. Conditional loops are a significant overhead, especially if the taken/not taken decision is effectively random.

Comment: Regarding the memory access, I would argue that in both cases it's similar since the object need be loaded in the CPU cache anyway. If we go in micro details, might as well point out that the first form might prevent lock contention on cache lines as the CPU core does not require exclusive access for a read ?

Comment: @MatthieuM. That sounded nifty! But can you explain it a bit more though? :p

Comment: @MattieuM: In the first case, the whole object is not loaded and more importantly, the data that is loaded is only used by the memory IO subsystem and not the CPU core. The second form could bypass the cache entirely.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on what you have simplified for the post. If you are adding a branch just to skip setting a variable, then you are probably not gaining anything and might be loosing if the branch prediction fails. I would remove the test.

Now, if the object to update is not a simple `int` then ... as always, measure, profile and then make a decision based on actual facts rather than hunches. If this is not part of a tight loop chances are that you will not even notice the difference either way.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever heard of [Loop Invariant Code Motion](http://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html#licm) ?

It is an optimization pass from compiler that moves code out of the body of loops whenever possible.

For example, given the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i) {
    if (argc < 100) {
      printf("%d\n", atoi(argv[1]));
    }
  }
}
```

Clang generates the following IR:

```
define i32 @main(i32 %argc, i8** nocapture %argv) nounwind {
  %1 = icmp sgt i32 %argc, 0
  br i1 %1, label %.lr.ph, label %._crit_edge

.lr.ph:                                           ; preds = %0
  %2 = icmp slt i32 %argc, 100
  %3 = getelementptr inbounds i8** %argv, i64 1
  br i1 %2, label %4, label %._crit_edge

; <label>:4                                       ; preds = %4, %.lr.ph
  %i.01.us = phi i32 [ %9, %4 ], [ 0, %.lr.ph ]
  %5 = load i8** %3, align 8, !tbaa !0
  %6 = tail call i64 @strtol(i8* nocapture %5, i8** null, i32 10) nounwind
  %7 = trunc i64 %6 to i32
  %8 = tail call i32 (i8*, ...)* @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([4 x i8]* @.str, i64 0, i64 0), i32 %7) nounwind
  %9 = add nsw i32 %i.01.us, 1
  %exitcond = icmp eq i32 %9, %argc
  br i1 %exitcond, label %._crit_edge, label %4

._crit_edge:                                      ; preds = %4, %.lr.ph, %0
  ret i32 0
}
```

Which can be translated back to C:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  if (argc == 0) { return 0; }

  if (argc >= 100) { return 0; }

  for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i) {
    printf("%d\n", atoi(argv[1]));
  }

  return 0;
}
```

**Conclusion:** don't bother with micro-optimizations unless a profiler reveals they are not as micro as you thought.

**EDIT:**

The edit radically changed the question (god I hate that :p). LICM does not apply any longer and the two functions have widely different functionalities.

The conclusion however remains identical. A single `if` check within a `for` loop does not change the fundamental complexity of your code (remember that the loop condition is tested at each iteration too...).

Comment: Sorry for the bad example. Great answer though :)
EDIT: and sorry for the edit :p

Answer (score 0):

For what I can tell `bState` isn't changed in the loop in the first fragment, so you can put `if` outside, which is obviously more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it really depends on the context. If it is critical for 
`bState`to be true during the bind, then the extra 1 or 2 assembly instructions per loop iteration to check the state will have to be paid. If not, leave out the 
`if`
when `x`is particularly large.